# How to test race condition of a redux observable epic

Tags: rxjs, jestjs, race-condition, redux-observable

I have a use case where I need to cancel an Ajax call and do something else in an epic. There's [an example](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/Cancellation.html) in the redux-observable doc which fits my need exactly. However, when I try to test the racing condition in my epic, the "cancelation" doesn't seem to work.

The example code is like:

```
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';

const fetchUserEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(FETCH_USER),
  mergeMap(action => race(
    ajax.getJSON(`/api/users/${action.payload}`).pipe(
      map(response => fetchUserFulfilled(response))
    ),
    action$.pipe(
      ofType(FETCH_USER_CANCELLED),
      map(() => incrementCounter()),
      take(1)
    )
  ))
);
```

My epic has the same structure as the example above, which is like:

```
initViewsEpic = (action$, state$, { ajaxGet }) => action$
  .ofType(INIT_VIEWS)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(() => race(
      ajaxGet('/api/views/...')
        .pipe(
          switchMap(response => of(
            initViewsFulFilled(response),
            taskCompleted(INIT_VIEWS),
          )),
          startWith(taskInProgress(INIT_VIEWS)),
          catchError(error => of(
             notification(),
             taskCompleted(INIT_VIEWS),
           )),
        ),
      action$.pipe(
        ofType(INIT_VIEWS_CANCEL),
        map(() => taskCompleted(INIT_VIEWS),
        take(1),
      ),
    )),
  );
```

And my test is like:

```
test('should ignore the ajax call response when INIT_VIEWS_CANCEL action is fired', (done) => {
    const action$ = ActionsObservable.of({ type: 'INIT_VIEWS' }, { type: 'INIT_VIEWS_CANCEL' });
    const ajaxGet = () => timer(3000);

   initViewsEpic(action$, state$, { ajaxGet })
      .pipe(toArray()).subscribe((actions) => {
        expect(actions).toEqual([
          {
            type: 'TASK_IN_PROGRESS',
            payload: { id: 'INIT_VIEWS' },
          },
          {
            type: 'TASK_COMPLETED',
            payload: { id: 'INIT_VIEWS' },
          },
        ]);
        done();
      });
  });
```

I suppose that since the `INIT_VIEWS_CANCEL` action follows the `INIT_VIEWS` action synchronously, it should "win" the `ajaxGet` and there should not be any `initViewsFulFilled` goes out. But the result of this test always returns `initViewsFulFilled` as the second output action of my epic (I am using jest to test the epic).

Is there anything I did wrong in my test? If so, how can I test this race condition in a redux-observable epic properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will say I'm going to give a suggestion to test redux observable epics (that's
what I've done) -- Use **TestScheduler in `rxjs/testing`**. So that we don't have to scratch the head dealing with ascyn things of other test frameworks

Here is the pseudo-code:

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ActionsObservable } from 'redux-observable';
import { TestScheduler } from 'rxjs/testing';
import { initViewsEpic } from '../actions';

const deepEquals = (actual, expected) => expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
const createTestScheduler = () => new TestScheduler(deepEquals);
let ts = {};

beforeEach(() => {
  ts = createTestScheduler();
});

afterEach(() => {
  ts.flush();
});

describe('initViewsEpic Epic', () => {
  const state$ = of(...);

  let values = {};

  beforeEach(() => {
    values = {
      a: { type: 'INIT_VIEWS' },
      b: { type: 'INIT_VIEWS_FULFILLED'},
      c: { type: 'INIT_VIEWS_CANCEL' },
      d: { type: 'TASK_IN_PROGRESS', payload: { id: 'INIT_VIEWS' } },
      e: { type: 'TASK_COMPLETED', payload: { id: 'INIT_VIEWS' } },
    };
  });

  test('in case of success') ...
  test('in case of error') ...

  test('in case of cancel', () => {
    const source = ActionsObservable.from(ts.createHotObservable('-ac----', values));
    const ajaxGet = () => () =>
      of({ response: 'arbitrary obj' }).pipe(delay(ts.createTime('---|'), ts));

    const actual = initViewsEpic(source, state$, { ajaxGet });

    ts.expectObservable(actual).toBe('-de---', values);
  });
});
```

Hope this can help someone who has the same problem as I did.

Comment: Could you share your final test code?

Comment: Hey @Caper, I've updated the answer with a pseudo-code example. I think this should be the right way to test redux observable epics.